# Xrdp on Debian 9 different display setup for remote session

Tags: debian, display-settings, xrdp

I have installed xrdp and tighervnc server

```
sudo apt install -y xrdp tigervnc-standalone-server
```

I am able to connect using Xorg and Xvnc (although Xvnc will sometimes display only black screen after login).

When working on my desktop I use two displays (monitors):

- display 1 contains a main panel + plank app + trash icon.
- display 2 contains my desktop files, icons etc. (no panels)

When I login remotely (I usually do it from a laptop with single lower resolution display), the desktop I see is without the main panel but with plank and with files and icons but not the trash icon.

**My questions is how can I setup different display setup / panel setup / etc. for my remote sessions?**

- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch)
- Kernel: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64
- Xfce: 4.12
- Xrdp: 0.9.1
- VNC: TigerVNC_standalone-server 1.7.0+dfsg-7